# Twitter share if app not installed

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, share

I am using below code for sharing video on twitter.It works fine if app is installed in the device but doesn't work if app is not there.How can i share video on twitter even if app is not installed in device?

```
File f = new File(extras.getString("filepath"));
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("video/*");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
                final PackageManager pm = mActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                final List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);

                for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {

                    if (("com.twitter.android.composer.ComposerActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name)) || ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name))) {

                        final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                        final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                        shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                        shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                        mActivity.getApplicationContext().startActivity(shareIntent);

                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Twitter's [Fabric](https://fabric.io) SDK

An implementation would something like this:

In your settings.gradle:

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
     jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }
 dependencies {

     classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
 }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
     jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }
}
```

In your build.gradle add the following dependencies:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:0.9.0@aar') {

    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.8.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

And then in your AndroidManifest.xml add the the following:

```
<application>
... 
<meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="YOUR FABIRC API KEY" />
</application>
```

And finally to use it in your activity:

Import the following:

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetComposer;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
```

In your oncreate function do:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new  TwitterAuthConfig("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new TweetComposer());
```

Then to send:

```
TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this).text(sendText);
File myFile = new File("path to your file");
Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(myFile);
builder.image(myUri);
builder.show();
```

Comment: no way related to the twitter both are completely different

Comment: @Nic Can i share video through Tweet Composer?Can u post some code for that?

Comment: Can i share video wid TweetComposer?

Comment: @Bhuvi Hey I've updated the code. I've only tested with images but my thinking is that you can just pass the uri of the video the same way.

Comment: +one for ur answer but i don't think tweet composer work for videos..i have used it for images previously..if it work for u for videos also then let me know

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you have to use Twitters api and post to user's account  or use SDK provided by them here's the link to the Android Sdk https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries
also use Twitter 4j to help you ease things and to code easier using the api. 
http://twitter4j.org/en/

Comment: @bhuvi was the link useful

Comment: Twitter4J doesn't support tweeting videos unfortunately